# Test Environment Assessment Methodology

Tags: test-management, quality-assessment

**Background**

Me and my colleges have been delegated the task to review a large company's testing process,
with focus on responsive design. As a part of our report, we've examined a couple of methods to assess the current test process as it is today, in order to find potential bottlenecks or improvement opportunities.

An interesting approach is one suggested by William E. Perry in [Effective Methods for Software Testing](https://www.google.se/books?hl=sv&lr=&id=q1WwdUZd7IAC&oi=fnd&pg=PR6&dq=software%20testing%20process%20assessment%20method&ots=EamDvqpwWM&sig=q2Ggdv8VzMcyldiN7JOOfWkjP14&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) (2006). In his book, Perry explains how to develop a [Kiviat Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart) or Footprint Chart (see figure 1) in order to get an overview of which parts of the process that are current for improvement. Perry refers to the [Quality Assurance Institute](http://www.qaiglobal.com/), which according to Perry have derived eight criteria that make a successful testing organization. The criteria are presented in figure 1.

[image: Figure 1]

*Figure 1, a Kiviat-Diagram, or Footprint Diagram, as suggested by Perry (2006)*

**Questions**

As I have no proffessional experience with test processes, some questions come to mind after reading.

- is this approach still valid and used today?
- Is this methodology well established and recognized?
- Are there any other, more viable options?

Answer (score 2):

Those sound like reasonable criteria, but our opinions are not as important as your stakeholders'.  You were asked to do this for a reason; perhaps someone in the organization thinks this large company's test process is deficient in some dimension.  Why not ask them whether there are any criteria besides the ones you listed that they would like for you to review?

Comment: We were given pretty much free hands to examine this. The main purpose of our work is to deliver suggestions on tools which could be useful for software testing. So we figured that some analysis was needed to be made, on how the test process is executed today. Then, we thought that maybe it's not the tools that's the problem, so now we are considering this approach to assess the quality of the current process on a wider perspective (but still delivering suggestions of tools, as per the requirement).